# disable apex:commandButton is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, button, conditional, disable

**Apex class:**

```
public Integer sCount {get;set;}

Attachments = [SELECT  Id,Name FROM Attachment WHERE Parentid =:caseId ];     
Integer sCount = Attachments.size();
```

**Vf page:**

```
<apex:commandButton disable= {!IF (sCount > 5,true,false)} value="Upload Attachments" action="{!upload}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to enclose `{!IF (sCount > 5,true,false)}` with `"` quotes.

Second, change `disable` to `disabled` according to attributes in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

Third,  `IF(sCount > 5,true,false)`  equals to `sCount > 5`

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{! sCount > 5}" value="Upload Attachments" action="{!upload}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below piece of code. Instead of `disable` it is `disabled`

```
<apex:commandButton disabled= "{!IF (sCount > 5,true,false)}" value="Upload Attachments" action="{!upload}"/>
```